# How can one change the url for a jquery ui tab added via 'add' and 'tabTemplate' functionality?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I might be making this more difficult than I need to but I am in some need of assistance.  I have some jquery ui tabs which are added via the add functionality.  these tabs are via ajax.

I have a tabTemplate set as follows on the initial addition of the tabs.

```
tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label},/a><li>"
```

And the add tab functionality is done via

```
$tabs.tabs('add', 'http://thanksforyourhelp/greatly/appreciated/, some_title_var)
```

If a form is submitted on that tab, data is written to the database.  The response gives an ID of the row added to the database.

Next time that specific tab is visited the link should actually be 'http://thanksforyourhelp/greatly/appreciated/ID' where the ID is now known since the response from the form (ajax here as well) sent it back.  This will pre-populate the forms on the page based off the data in the database for "ID."

I've looked at the example [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode), but my href is an id for the tab in question (and not a url).  Where is the actual url stored?

The tab looks like this.

```
<a href="#ui-tabs-6">new</a>
```

I have tried changing the href on that, but upon clicking the tab the content is loaded without ajax instead of within the tab as desired.  What might I be doing wrong here?  Thanks for your help.

*Edit*: removed edits with references of no longer existent urls.

Comment: Is it possible for you to set up a small example?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I have added an example.  I tried to explain as best I could.  Let me know what I should try and clarify more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with AJAX-powered tabs too much, but I think you want the `url` method:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("url", index, url)
```

> Change the url from which an Ajax
>   (remote) tab will be loaded. The
>   specified URL will be used for
>   subsequent loads. Note that you can
>   not only change the URL for an
>   existing remote tab with this method,
>   but also turn an in-page tab into a
>   remote tab.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Thanks.  I'm looking at this.  I had tried something like this before and didn't have any luck.  I'm wondering if I've got my index stuff screwed up though...which would explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker  Thanks again for your suggestion.  Like I said in the previous comment, I think I tried that before.  Your answer does seem to be right though, so I think I have something wrong on my end.  I'm wondering if I need to force reloading of the tab on click, as upon examination of some apache logs clicking back on the tab doesn't seem to be making any requests.  Hmmm.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: @wilbbe01: Could it be some kind of caching issue?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, it's possible.  I did just realize I was overlooking an error with my ui tabs though.  I'm getting a "o.ajaxOptions.success is not a function" which after failing makes all ajax stop working on the page.  So I have the right code for switching the tab url now, thank you.  Just need to find out why this ajax success thing fails on loading of a tab.  Very similar symptoms (and relation) to this bug that was fixed a while ago....but different problem... http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4451.

Comment: @wilbb01: Interesting--Probably an issue worth opening another question over.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, yeah, I'll post if I can't figure out the cause.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer will not work in JQuery 1.9+ as describer [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-url-method-and-use-of-title-attribute-use-aria-controls-attribute). To work with jquery ui tabs 1.9+ you have to do something like this

```
var tabs = $("#tabs");
var tab = $(tabs.data('uiTabs').tabs[TAB_INDEX]);
tab.find('.ui-tabs-anchor').attr('href', "NEW_URL");
// If cached initially. Remove cache then
tab.data( "loaded", false);
tabs.tabs( "option", "active", TAB_INDEX);
tabs.tabs("load", TAB_INDEX);
```

This will change the URL of tab at particular index and load that tab.